# C# .NET Create a DateTime object in UK timezone (I am in Central US)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I do not want to convert CST to GMT or UK Time. I want to create a UK DateTime object with value of "2019-10-01 00:00:00"

Like: DateTime ukTime = new DateTime(2019,10,1);  // BUT this gives me local US Central time as I live there

I can convert this "ukTime" from CST to UK Time but then it will not be 2019/10/01 in UK Time.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a time zone component. It's only CST because that's your system's configured time zone.

Comment: Take a look at `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: Better yet, take a look at [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime/). It forces you to be explicit and careful about what you want, and you'll be talking about actual time zones instead of offsets.  **Time Zone != Offset**

Comment: The last  two paragraphs in the question are incorrect. The object you get won't represent any time zone in particular, as the default `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` when you use that constructor. It could be intended to mean anywhere on the planet.